# Is there a way to use standard CLR functions on Azure SQL Edge for Ubuntu Docker on an M1 Mac?

Tags: docker, sql-clr, macos, azure-sql-edge

I have a MacBook with an M1 chip, so (about) the only option for me to run SQL Server is to [run it as a Docker container](https://database.guide/how-to-install-sql-server-on-an-m1-mac-arm64/). This works fine for standard SQL, but our application uses some CLR features like [`COMPRESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/compress-transact-sql); when I try to use that, it tells me

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 45
> Common Language Runtime(CLR) is not enabled on this instance.

[Enabling it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/clr-integration-enabling) does not work:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

gives

> Msg 15392, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 166
> The specified option 'clr enabled' is not supported by this edition of SQL Server and cannot be changed using sp_configure.

I found [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59690813/4751173) but that is about someone using a custom .NET library; I'm looking for the 'standard' functionality available in SQL Server for Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an easier path to this now, as of Ventura (I tested on 13.3) and Docker 4.16.

1. Make sure you are on macOS Ventura - I only *know* that it works on 13.3 because I can’t test anything earlier now
2. Make sure Docker is the "Apple Chip" version, 4.16 or later:

   > [image: Get the right chip]
3. Enable "Use Virtualization Framework" in `Settings` > `General`:

   > [image: Enable "Use Virtualization Framework"]
4. Enable "Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 Emulation…" under `Settings` > `Features in Development`:

   > [image: Enable "Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 Emulation…"]
5. Hit <kbd>Apply & Restart</kbd>
6. Create a new container adding the important `--platform=linux/amd64` argument; while it should work for any image in [the hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server), this command is for SQL Server 2022, and is the only one where [I have validated that it works](https://sqlblog.org/2023/03/03/sql-server-apple-silicon):

   ```
   docker run --platform=linux/amd64           \
     -e ACCEPT_EULA=1                          \
     -e MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=sTr0ng3st_p@ssw0rd!  \
     -p 1433:1433 -d                           \     
     mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
   ```
7. Proof that `COMPRESS()` works:

   > [image: Glorfindel pudding]

Comment: In Docker Desktop 4.26, the feature seems to have been promoted out of beta; I could skip steps 3 and 4.

Comment: @Glorfindel Not at a suitable machine at the moment but are these options located elsewhere (and both enabled by default)?

Comment: 'Use Virtualization framework' is still under General, activated, but I can't deactivate it. And now that I have a second look, 'Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon' is there as well (activated by default). Here's a screenshot you could use: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhBBA.png

Answer (score 3):

You are not alone [running SQL Server container images on MacBook Pro M1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7099/testing-sql-server-edge-and-docker-on-the-latest-macbooks/): and in fact CLR is missing from Azure SQL Edge container images.

However a brave person was able to install [SQL Server 2019  on Windows Server 2016 on a M1 Max MacBook Pro](https://bornsql.ca/blog/sql-server-2019-on-apple-silicon-redux-it-actually-works/) by using an emulator called [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app/), which itself is an abstraction over [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/).

The recommended x86_64 architecture is this:

```
Standard PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009) (alias of pc-q35-6.1) (q35)
```

Use it as the basis of your virtual machine and configured it with two CPU cores, 8GB RAM, and a 127GB virtual hard drive.